# Top two latest records in Dataframe

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe

I have an Apache Spark Dataframe with following data in it(ID, Name, DATE):

```
ID,Name,DATE
1,Anil,2000-06-02
1,Anil,2000-06-03
1,Anil,2000-06-04
2,Arun,2000-06-05
2,Arun,2000-06-06
2,Arun,2000-06-07
3,Anju,2000-06-08
3,Anju,2000-06-09
3,Anju,2000-06-10
4,Ram,2000-06-11
4,Ram,2000-06-02
4,Ram,2000-06-03
4,Ram,2000-06-04
5,Ramu,2000-06-05
5,Ramu,2000-06-06
5,Ramu,2000-06-07
5,Ramu,2000-06-08
6,Renu,2000-06-09
7,Gopu,2000-06-10
7,Gopu,2000-06-11
```

But I want the top two latest records of ID, and I would like to get the following output:

```
ID,Name,DATE
1,Anil,2000-06-03
1,Anil,2000-06-04
2,Arun,2000-06-06
2,Arun,2000-06-07
3,Anju,2000-06-09
3,Anju,2000-06-10
4,Ram,2000-06-03
4,Ram,2000-06-04
5,Ramu,2000-06-07
5,Ramu,2000-06-08
6,Renu,2000-06-09
7,Gopu,2000-06-10
7,Gopu,2000-06-11
```

Do I need to use window functions like Lag?

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: It's an Apache Spark DF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with a `COUNT` < 2.

```
SELECT d.ID, d.Name, d.Date
FROM Dataframetable d
LEFT OUTER JOIN Dataframetable d2 ON d2.ID = d.ID AND d.Date < d2.Date
GROUP BY d.ID, d.Name, d.Date
HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
```

Output

```
ID  Name    Date
1   Anil    2000-06-03T00:00:00Z
1   Anil    2000-06-04T00:00:00Z
2   Arun    2000-06-06T00:00:00Z
2   Arun    2000-06-07T00:00:00Z
3   Anju    2000-06-09T00:00:00Z
3   Anju    2000-06-10T00:00:00Z
4   Ram     2000-06-04T00:00:00Z
4   Ram     2000-06-11T00:00:00Z
5   Ramu    2000-06-07T00:00:00Z
5   Ramu    2000-06-08T00:00:00Z
6   Renu    2000-06-09T00:00:00Z
7   Gopu    2000-06-10T00:00:00Z
7   Gopu    2000-06-11T00:00:00Z
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8dcc2/1/0

Using Sub query rather than self join.

```
SELECT ID, name, date FROM (SELECT d.ID, d.Name, MAX(d.Date) Date
FROM Dataframetable d
GROUP BY d.ID, d.Name
UNION ALL
SELECT d.ID, d.Name, MAX(d.Date)
FROM Dataframetable d
WHERE d.Date NOT IN 
(SELECT date FROM (SELECT d.ID, d.Name, MAX(d.Date) Date
FROM Dataframetable d
GROUP BY d.ID, d.Name) a)
GROUP BY d.ID, d.Name) b
ORDER BY ID
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8dcc2/19/0

Comment: thanks @Matt any idea how we can do it without self join.

Comment: @PardeepSharma added answer that doesn't need self join, although i would imagine this will be slower.

Comment: can you please share a link which can explain why sub query is slower than self join. or it'll be good if you can explain.

Comment: Not definitely, just assuming it will be, I don't know your data, run both queries with an explain plan and see for your self.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Matt - your solution works fine with Apache Spark I tested it.

```
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DFTest").setMaster("local[5]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
  val hadoopConf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

  val myFile = sc.textFile("C:\\DFTest\\DFTest.txt")

  case class Record(id: Int, name: String, datetime : String) 
  val myFile1 = myFile.map(x=>x.split(",")).map {
    case Array(id, name, datetime) => Record(id.toInt, name,datetime)
  }

  import sqlContext.implicits._

  val myDF = myFile1.toDF()

  myDF.registerTempTable("deep_cust")

  sqlContext.sql("SELECT d.id, d.name, d.datetime FROM deep_cust d " +
    "LEFT OUTER JOIN deep_cust d2 ON d2.id = d.id AND d.datetime < d2.datetime " +
    "GROUP BY d.id, d.name, d.datetime " +
    "HAVING COUNT(*) < 2").show()
```

But it wont work directly with Hive because Hive wont support non-equi joins, we have to use some other alternative like RANK.

**Alternate Approach:**

@Matt Could you please suggest me if the below RANK solution is faster than joins. If not then we have to use where clause instead of **AND d.Date < d2.Date**
 .

```
select x.id,x.name,x.datetime from (select id,name,datetime,rank() over (partition by id,name order by datetime desc) as rownum from deep_cust) x where x.rownum<3;
```